Can the first boss's transformation attack be avoided?
The first boss of Hades II, Headmistress Hecate, has an attack where she throws a homing orb that temporarily turns you into a sheep. Is there any way to avoid her sheep attack?

There are several ways to dodge the orb in question (the first one requires to progress a bit in the game):

 - The easiest and quickest way is to let Frinos, your frog friend, join you and absorb the orb by hiding behind it.


The other way is a bit harder to master, but it involves dashing not away from the orb, but through it. If you time it nicely, you can dodge through it a few times, and it will disappear after 5/6 dodges usually. You can also help yourself with sprint boosting boons, or the Swift Runner arcana to run faster and have an instant dodge, making it easier.

Using any of those methods successfully will even make Hecate use special dialog lines.

I was able to get the dashing technique to work. I made a video showing the technique in action. You may want to put the first point in spoiler tags. I hadn't unlocked them when I asked this question.
